# How do I unhide hidden column in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, column, hidden

I've upgraded a SP2007 to a SP2010 and now some settings have been lost. In some CQWP I need the *Created* column to group items etc. How do I unhide it so it is selectable in dropdownlists and displays in list settings when overviewing columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this programmatically or through PowerShell, setting [SPField.Hidden](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.hidden.aspx) property to false.

Tentative PowerShell script:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://localhost
$list = $web.GetList("/Lists/Test")
$field = $list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Created")
$field.Hidden = $false
$field.Update()
```

Comment: Let me know do you have any script for SharePoint online or can we use same for SharePoint online for unhide column "Item is a Record"